# Showing the Lorentz-Fitzgerald length contraction

Tags: special-relativity

I'm trying to show that if we have a rod of length $L$ that is at rest wrt the inertial frame $K$, and we have a observer $K'$ moving wrt $K$ with speed $v_0$ in the direction along the length of the rod, than the moving observer will measure the length of the rod as $\sqrt{1-\beta^2} L$, i.e trying to show **Lorentz-Fitzgerald length contraction.**

However, when I set up a *Gedankenexperiment*, I fail to get the desired result, **so which part of my argument in below is wrong ?**

[image]

Let at time $t=0$, the origins of $K$ and $K'$ be at the same place, (we define $t=0$ as the time when $K'$ passes from the origin), and at the time $t=0$, we send two signals from the end points of the rod toward the $+x$ axis, so that both signals will be received by $K'$ at a later time.

Since the signal send from the point $B$ (right end of the rod) will be received also at $t =0$ since $K'$ is also at $x=0$ when $t=0$, the coordinates of the event that the $K'$ observer receives the signal sent from $B$ are $t_{s_1} = 0$ and $x_{s_1} = 0$ wrt $K$ and $t'_{s_1} = 0$ and $x'_{s_2} = 0$ wrt $K'$.

Now, **wrt $K$**, the signal sent from the point $A$ (the left end of the rod) will reach $K'$ at $t= \frac{L}{c-v_0}$, at which point $K'$ will be at $x=\frac{v_0 L}{c-v_0}$. Therefore, the coordinates of the event that the signal sent from the left end the rod is received will have the coordinates $t_{s_2} = \frac{L}{c-v_0}$ and $x_{s_2} = =\frac{v_0 L}{c-v_0}$ wrt $K$ frame.

To find $t'_{s_2}$ and $x'_{s_2}$, we use Lorentz Transformations;

$$x_{s_2}' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}} (\frac{v_0 L}{c-v_0} - \frac{c L}{c-v_0} \cdot \frac{v_0}{c}  ) = 0$$
and

$$t_{s_2}' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}} (\frac{-v_0^2 L}{c^2 (c-v_0)} + \frac{L}{c-v_0}  ) = \frac{-L}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}},$$

but if that is the case, this means that the first equation tells that the moving observer receives the both signal simultaneously at $x'=0$, but it cannot be true since the light has to travel some distance even in wrt $K'$ frame, and the second equation also tells us that observer receives the signal at a later time than $t'=0$, so the observer should be moving, which is correct wrt $K'$, but if we multiply $t'_{s_2}$ with $c$ to get the distance between $A$ and $K'$ wrt $K'$, we get $\frac{L}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}} $, which is wrong.

Comment: @marmot Isn't an observer a reference frame also ? I've used the words frame and observer interchangeable in the question above.

Comment: Well, but you are saying that $K$ moves w.r.t. $K$. This is at least confusing. IMHO the rest frame of the rod and the relatively moving observer should be named differently. Likewise your last equation looks odd. How is $v_0^2/c^2>1$?

Comment: @marmot ıt is just a typo, edited.

Comment: @marmot exactly where $x_0^2 / c^2 > 1 $ ?

Comment: The equation shows $v_0^2/c^2$. In any case, if $\text{something}^2/c^2>1$, "something" has to be a velocity for dimensional reasons. So "something" is a velocity that exceeds the speed of light. How is that possible?

Comment: @marmot I'm having trouble to understand what you mean, can you be more clear on what exactly are you talking about ?

Comment: The left-hand side of your last equation is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\left(\frac{-v_0^2L}{c^2(c-v_0)}-\frac{L}{c-v_0}\right)=\frac{L}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\left[\frac{L}{c-v_0}\left(\frac{-v_0^2}{c^2}+1\right)\right]$. If this is to yield your right-hand side, the square bracket has to become $-1$. How is that possible?

Comment: @marmot the sign of $\frac{L}{c-v_0} $ should be $+$ in RHS of your equation.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Thanks, But this shows the problem.